# finding a certain tr by attribute in an array of tr's

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi im trying to find a tr inside an array of tr's
the attribute name is docId

is there anykind of jquery selector for this?

i dont want to just iterate throught the array with a for loop
and find it myself.

unlesss you will say i have no choice...

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you already have the array of trs on hand, and you got them through a jquery selector

```
array.filter('tr[attr=val]')
```

may be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('tr[name=docId]')
```

That makes usage of the 'Attribute equals` selector. If your're dealing with a jQuery wrappet set, this is probably what you want.

Even, if that selector internally will also iterate over the set.

Ref.: [Attribute Equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: where is the array in all this?...

the tr's are not in the html.

Comment: @guy: well you're right actually. But a `jQuery wrapped set` also represents an Array. So my guess was, you're dealing with such a structure. Otherwise the word `jQuery selector` would really be confusing and infact wrong in the question.