# d3 select a table row with multiple arguments

Tags: d3.js

I have a "quick" question - I have the following rows in a html table:

```
<tr ch-id="1">    
<td>...</td> 

<tr ch-id="2">    
<td>...</td>
...
```

I want to select the row with the unique channel ID (ch-id). How can I cascade my selection?

```
d3.selectAll('tr,[ch-id="2"]')
```

does not work...

thx!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would work the same as dom selections in jQuery. If you are trying to select all tr(s) with ch-id=2, I think it would work d3.selectAll('tr [ch-id="2"]'). you could try to change the html to data-chid=2 and then use the $().data('chid') selector.

Answer (score 0):

I also think it should be the same as jQuery's selector syntax, but as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509382/finding-a-certain-tr-by-attribute-in-an-array-of-trs) says, you shouldn't have the space between the two elements. That is, it should be `'tr[ch-id="2"]'` with no space between the `tr` and the `[ch-id="2"]`.

I think if you did have the space, it'd select all the elements with `ch-id` 2 that were nested under a tr.